# Python IndexError On Conditional Statement

Tags: python, string, error-handling, indexing, range

If I test the "empty" condition of the following, I get an IndexError that states the string index is out of range. Why is that? I want the script to print "empty" if the user input is empty.

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    if first in 'aeiou':
        print "vowel"
        new_word = original + pyg
        print new_word
    else:
        new_word = word[1:len(original)] + first + pyg
        print new_word
else:
    print "empty"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first = word[0]
```

is failing; if `word` is empty, there *is* no zeroth character. You can replace this by

```
first = word[:1]
```

But since it's only used inside the `if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():` branch, it'd be better to move it inside instead and leave it as `first = word[0]`.

BTW, instead of `if len(original) > 0)`, you can simply write `if original` -- nonempty strings are truelike.

Comment: Actually, you could get rid of that test all together... `''.isalpha()` returns `False` :) -- But, I suppose that doesn't make the point about good style for sequence truthfulness checking ...

Comment: @mgilson: oy, good call!  I can never remember what functions in which languages return vacuously true and which ones don't. :^)

Comment: I learned several things from your answer in addition to what I was asking about. Thanks!